# Script typo3 handling the __exec_command event returned with error code 1

Tags: installation, typo3, typo3-11.x

I'm trying to install Typo3 CMS for a website project but keep getting installation errors. I did all the installation process of Typo3 using XAMPP with composer and after I run "composer exec typo3 setup" in XAMPP shell this is the error I got:

```
Database driver?
[mysqli        ] [MySQLi] Manually configured MySQL TCP/IP connection
[mysqliSocket  ] [MySQLi] Manually configured MySQL socket connection
[pdoMysql      ] [PDO] Manually configured MySQL TCP/IP connection
[pdoMysqlSocket] [PDO] Manually configured MySQL socket connection
[postgres      ] Manually configured PostgreSQL connection
[sqlite        ] Manually configured SQLite connection
```

> 

```
Aborted.


setup [--driver [DRIVER]] [--host HOST] [--port PORT] [--dbname DBNAME] [--username USERNAME] [--password PASSWORD] [--admin-username ADMIN-USERNAME] [--admin-user-password ADMIN-USER-PASSWORD] [--admin-email ADMIN-EMAIL] [--project-name PROJECT-NAME] [--create-site [CREATE-SITE]] [--force] [-n|--no-interaction]`

Script typo3 handling the __exec_command event returned with error code 1`
```

Comment: What happens when you use the Install Tool GUI  https://example-project-site.local/typo3/install.php